# How to manage Process and ProcessBuilder objects from Java WebApplication

Tags: java, spring, process

From my java web application I am creating process object and after passing commands I am starting the process.
Along with the process start I am maintaining another thread which is keeping a look at the exit value of the current process.

Does this `process.exitValue()` causes the current thread to wait?

**Updated Question:**
Please can you give some information about why process.destroy() is able to kill gcc(for c and c++) , java processes, but while coming to c# programs running in mono these processes cannot be destroyed, why?

And can I get pid value from the Process object while running it in ubuntu server to kill the process by pid ?

Comment: What does its documentation say?

Comment: Returns the exit value for the subprocess.
Returns:
the exit value of the subprocess represented by this Process object. By convention, the value 0 indicates normal termination.
Throws:
IllegalThreadStateException - if the subprocess represented by this Process object has not yet terminated

But not mentioned anything about wait. You can see for waitFor() its mentioned. @Kayaman

Comment: Of course it doesn't mention waiting. It throws an exception if the process hasn't terminated, so there's no waiting happening but plenty of exception throwing.

Answer (score 0):

To wait end of created process you can use `Process.waitFor()`
`exitValue` doesn't wait process termination. Moreover it will throw exception in case if process still in progress.